# Natural Language Processing: Identifying Words That Are Out of Place?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, audio-recognition

I want to make it easier to manually (or potentially automatically) correct AI transcription. I've noticed that one significant error that can be very easily picked up by human transcriptionists is words that are just out of place in a sentence.

I am wondering if there is a system (algorithmic or something complete like a node.js package) that can score words for out-of-placeness in a group of paragraphs. I imagine it would involve a lot of algorithmic learning.

Comment: Consider reading up on the topic TF-IDF.

Comment: One could maybe use n-grams for this, computing scores.

Comment: Btw, this problem is basically an anomaly detection problem. So techniques from sequence/time-series anomaly detection might be useful.